# Protractor e2e Testing ui grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

For accessing grid objects in Angular JS, I am hoping to use the APIs provided at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.

But after going through the APIs, in https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/master/test/e2e/gridTestUtils.spec.js, for accessing a grid object, I need to know about Grid ID.

```js
/**
  * Helper function for returning a grid element.
  * @param gridId Id of grid to return.
  *
  * @returns {ElementFinder|Grid}  Grid wrapped in an ElementFinder
  *
  * @example
  * <pre>
  *   var grid = gridTestUtils.getGrid( 'myGrid' ); //or internally
  *   var row = this.getGrid( gridId );
  * </pre>
  */
  getGrid: function( gridId ) {
    return element( by.id( gridId ) );
  },
```

But, in my Angular JS webapp, the ID is getting assigned to the grid dynamically at runtime.

```js
<div role="grid" ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="'grid-container'" class="ui-grid-render-container ng-isolate-scope ui-grid-render-container-body" ng-style="{ 'margin-left': colContainer.getMargin('left') + 'px', 'margin-right': colContainer.getMargin('right') + 'px' }" ui-grid-render-container="" container-id="'body'" col-container-name="'body'" row-container-name="'body'" bind-scroll-horizontal="true" bind-scroll-vertical="true" enable-horizontal-scrollbar="grid.options.enableHorizontalScrollbar" enable-vertical-scrollbar="grid.options.enableVerticalScrollbar" aria-multiselectable="false" id="1476870709232-grid-container" style="margin-left: 35px; margin-right: 0px;">
```

How to get the value of "id" of the grid in protractor test, to access the grid structure?

Comment: Use a CSS selector with a partial id to get your grid: `element(by.css("[id$='-grid-container']"))`

Comment: It Worked !! Thanks Florent !